# Compare two pandas data frame from csv

Tags: pandas, concatenation, drop-duplicates

I have 2 csv files and i need to compare them using by pandas. The values in these two files are the same so I expect the df result to be empty but it shows to me they are different. Do you think i miss something when i read csv files? or another things to test/fix?

```
df1=pd.read_csv('apc2019.csv', sep = '|', lineterminator=True)
df2=pd.read_csv('apc2020.csv', sep = '|', lineterminator=True)
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of those 2 csv files?

Comment: Those 2 files are totally same the inside looks like that:  TYPE|TYPE|SNTYPE|RECORD
XDFE|TOTAL|BEFKLON|-54.36
XDFE|IFX|SOCCON|75.46

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to find what's the difference first, but it is hard with the `pd.equals` since it will only give you either `True` or `False`, can you try this?

```
from pandas._testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

This will tell you exactly the difference, and it has different levels of 'tolerance' (for example if you don't care about the column names, of the types etc)

Details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

If you want to compare with a tolerance in values:

```
In [20]: from pandas._testing import assert_frame_equal 
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [1, 9]}) 
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 5], 'c': [1.5, 8.5]})                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [21]: assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_less_precise=-1, check_dtype=False)
```

By defaut `chekc_dtype` is True, so it will raise an exception if you have floats vs ints.

The other parameter to change is the `check_less_precise` by using negatives you make the allowed error bigger

Comment: first of all thank you so much! it helps a lot to see whats wrong. Now i am facing another problem; I round values to compare and for those kind of values: -14209.496 & -14209.50  it rounds to -14210.0 & -14209.0  that's why it couldnt match them :(  Would you give me any commands how to fix it? Thank you